# conditionally edit a single row in csv stream in node.js

Tags: node.js, csv, fs

what i'm trying to do:
i'm trying to read a large csv, check for a true or false flag in each row if false i want to get that row do some operations and change the flag to true then move on to next row.

what i have been able to do:
i am able to read or write a file stream (using `fs.createReadStream and fs.createWriteStream`) from start to end (using `json2csv` and `csvtojson` in node.js). need to figure out a way to read to some operation if condition satisfy write/edit that row and move on